# How to create custom upload adapter for pdf Files in CKEDITOR 5 angular

Tags: angular8, ckeditor5

We working on create chat editor, where the files can be upload(Pdf,Doc) to the each message and file should be converted to base64 and saved with message in db(functionality same lile ms teams app). So we have opted for ckeditor 5 angular editor. And we done with UI and tools config. Now I stuck with uploading the files for message. I have gone through documentation it helped little better. If anyone have idea in implementing this help me. Thanks...